# How to upload videos to youtube from url

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, youtube-api

I have an option for users to share videos. I use to filepicker.io to handle my uploads. I am using zend gdata plugin, it works well for videos stored on my server. But it does not work for videos saved on amazon s3 servers. Can I upload videos on s3 to youtube.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The YouTube Data API requires that you send the actual bytes of the video you're uploading as part of the upload request. You can't just provide a reference to a remote URL as part of an upload request and expect the YouTube API servers to retrieve the video file from that URL.

If your video is on Amazon S3 and your code is running from a place that doesn't have direct access to the video file, then you're going to have to download it temporarily to someplace your code does have access to, and then include the video file in your YouTube upload request.